# For how many 3-digit prime numbers $\overline{abc}$ do we have: $b^2-4ac=9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> For how many 3-digit prime numbers $\overline{abc}$ do we have: $b^2-4ac=9$?

The only analysis I did is:
$(b-3)(b+3)=4ac \implies\ b\geq3 $
$b=3\implies\ c=0\implies impossible!!$
So I deduced that $b\gt3$
Is there any better way for quickly solving this??
Or maybe a trick applies...

Comment: You also know that $c$ can only be $1,3,7,9$ otherwise the prime number would be divisible by $2$ or $5$. Also $a+b+c \neq 3$, $\neq 6$ nor $\neq 9$ otherwise it would be divisible by $3$. Don't know if this really helps !

Comment: @Zubzub: if you also excluded digit sums of $12,15,18$ etc. and cases where $b$ is even, that would leave $451=11 \times 41$ and $299=13 \times 23$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square and makes $ax^2+bx+c$ factor-able. Then$$\overline{abc}=10^2 a+10b+c=(10A+B)(10C+D)$$will never be a prime!

Comment: Excellent!!!! This is mathematical Talent!!!

Comment: But another question rises here: Can we say that if $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square then the equation: $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has integer roots??!!  I think this must be deeply checked...

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: in general such an equation has rational roots, such as  $4x^2+5x+1=0$  with $b^2-4ac=9$ which has the roots $x=-\frac14, -1$.  The point here is a little more subtle, since in this example the factorisation is $(4x+1)(x+1)$, and setting $x=10$ gives $451=41\times 11$.  In general the factorisation involves integers even if the roots need not be integers

Comment: @Henry Thank you dear:)

Comment: What if (10A+B)=1

Comment: $a=AC \neq 0$ because we have a three digit number.

Answer (score 3):

$b$ is odd because $4ac$ is even.
You only have three choices for $b$.  In each case, calculate exactly what $4ac$ equals.  There may be a few choices for $a$ and $c$.  See whether $\overline{abc}$ is prime.

Comment: Allowing $a$ and $c$ to be single digits and being generous, you get $030=2 \times 15$, $154=2\times 77$, $252 = 2\times 126$, $451=11 \times 41$, $275=5\times 55$, $572=2\times 286$, $299=13 \times 23$, $396=2 \times 198$, $693=3\times 231$, $992=2 \times 496$

Answer (score 1):

$(b-3)(b+3) = 4ac$
Now, $4ac$ is an even number. Hence, $(b-3)(b+3)$ is also and even number. That means, b cannot be even number else, $(b-3)(b+3)$ will if odd. 
Hence, $b > 3$ and b is odd. Thus, b can be 5, 7, 9.

Putting, the values for b:

When $b = 5$, we get $4ac = (5-3)(5+3) = 2 * 8 = 16$ or $ac = 4 = 2*2 = 1*4$. No prime numbers possible with these combinations.

When $b = 7$, we get $4ac = (7-3)(7+3) = 4.10 = 40$ or $ac = 10 = 2*5$. Again, no combinations possible.

When $b = 9$, we get $4ac = (9-3)(9+3) = 6.12 = 72$ or $ac = 18 = 2*9 = 3*6$. Again, no combinations possible.

Thus, no such 3 digit prime number exists.