# Showing that there are no $3$-digit primes $\overline {abc}$ such that $b^2-4ac=9$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Problem: Show that there are no $3$-digit primes $\overline {abc}$ such that $b^2-4ac=9$.
>   Solution. Upon the given condition, the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$ can be written as $(px+q)(rx+s)$ and we have:
>    $$\overline{abc}=100a+10b+c=(10p+q)(10r+s)$$
>   i.e. $\overline{abc}$ is not a prime which is a contradiction, so there is no such prime available.

I don't get the reasoning completely.

Comment: Well...it is certainly natural to write down the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$.  Can you show that the roots are rational?

Comment: @lulu Yes , of course

Comment: Ok...so given that, let us say the roots are $x=-\frac pq$,$x=-\frac rs$ for natural numbers $p,q,r,s$.  (it is clear that the roots are both $<0$, yes?).  But this is all they have written!

Comment: I don't understand the decomposition of $\overline{abc}$

Comment: $\overline{abc}=100a+10b+c$ by the very definition of our base 10 number system.  For example $132 = 1\cdot 100 + 3\cdot 10 + 2\cdot 1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz , my trouble is with: $(10p+q)(10r+s)$

Comment: As for rewriting it in terms of $(10p+q)(10r+s)$, this follows from our earlier observation that we could rewrite the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ as $(px+q)(rx+s)$ and then setting $x=10$.

Comment: OP posted the same problem 1 year 4 months ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843436/for-how-many-3-digit-prime-numbers-overlineabc-do-we-have-b2-4ac-9?rq=1

Comment: @user236182: That is rather strange ... Why would someone post the same problem after such a long time? Perhaps OP could clarify?

Comment: @String You know,I met that problem again and thought about it from a rather different point of view(unfortunately I didn't remember it!).On the other hand,you see this time a more detailed answer was given which is quite elaborative to me.I really learned more this time,many thanks to Robert Z.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: OK, I see. That makes sense to me. Cheers! Though it appears to me, that what you were really after this time was an argument as to why $a,b,c$ being integers and $ax^2+bx+c$ having rational roots would imply $ax^2+bx+c=(px+q)(rx+s)$. Is that right?

Comment: @String Thank you.Yes indeed.Interestingly,I still don't get Robert's answer completely since I ask: Why are you sure that $p$ divides $20a+b-d$ or $20a+b+d$??

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: That is a property of prime numbers, called Euclid's Lemma: if a prime $p$ divedes a product $ab$, then it divides at least one of the factors $a$ or $b$. The proof is rather non-trivial as it requires another result called Bezout's Lemma, which takes some more work. It is not extremely advanced stuff, but it does take some considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** I fixed the problem that originally occured, so I have removed the disclaimer again. But the proof got a bit more complicated in order to establish that $a$ must be a multiple of $nv$.

---

Let me provide the proof of the following result, which should connect the dots in the original solution given in the OP:

> If $a,b,c$ are integers and $ax^2+bx+c$ has rational roots, then
>   $$
> ax^2+bx+c=(px+q)(rx+s)
> $$

for some integers $p,q,r$, and $s$. To see this, assume the two roots to be $\tfrac mn$ and $\tfrac uv$ where both fractions have been simplified to their lowest terms. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
ax^2+bx+c&=a(x-\tfrac mn)(x-\tfrac uv)\\
&=ax^2-a(\tfrac mn+\tfrac uv)x+a\tfrac mn\tfrac uv
\end{align}
$$
Hence it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
b&=-a\tfrac{mv+nu}{nv}\\
c&=a\tfrac{mu}{nv}
\end{align}
$$
Now suppose both fractions above could be expressed in terms of some common denominator $nv/p$ for some prime $p$. Combining the facts that $m/n$ and $u/v$ are in their lowest terms, but $\frac{mu}{nv}$ is not, it then follows by Euclid's Lemma, that $p$ divides either the pair $n,u$ or the pair $m,v$. In either case it cannot divide the other numerator $mv+nu$ since it divedes one of the terms but is relatively prime to the other. Hence no such common factor $p$ exists. Thus $nv$ is the least common denominator, and therefore $a$ must be a multiple of $nv$.

Now write $a=\lambda nv$. Then it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
a(x-\tfrac mn)(x-\tfrac uv)
&=\lambda nv(x-\tfrac mn)(x-\tfrac uv)\\
&=(\lambda nx-\lambda m)(vx-u)
\end{align}
$$
which has the form $(px+q)(rx+s)$ with $p,q,r$, and $s$ all integers.

---

By the way, this easily provides the foundation for reaching the general result:

> Show that $\overline{abc}$ with $b^2-4ac=d^2$ where $abc=100a+10b+c$ is a $3$-digit number and $d$ is a natural number can never be a prime number.

**Solution:** Since $d^2$ is a perfect square, the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ must be rational. They must also be non-positive, since $d^2\leq b^2$, and thus we have
$$
ax^2+bx+c=(px+q)(rx+s)
$$
for some natural numbers $p,q,r$, and $s$. Plugging in $x=10$ we get
$$
100a+10b+c=(10p+q)(10r+s)
$$
proving that $\overline{abc}$ can be non-trivially factored into two factors greater than or equal to $10$.

Comment: Bravo:) Your answer is quite new to me! I have never seen or heared of it(+1).Thank you dear String

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: I did not know this result beforehand, which is why I had to come up with a proof. It might well be some special case of a more general result that "everyone" knows. Though I have a Master's Degree in mathematics, I did not recognize this result. Blunder on my part, probably :) Glad that it brought some new light to your understanding as well!

Comment: I can't believe this problem is getting so complicated: as String noted his error,now $p,q,r,s$ are not determined exactly!!

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: I fixed the problem. It ended up in the same place, so the argument should hold now.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: And by the way, we got around to Euclid's Lemma anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

We show a more general fact:

> There is no $3$-digit primes $\overline {abc}$ such that $b^2-4ac=d^2$ where $d$ is a non-negative integer.

We first note that $d\leq b\leq 9$. Since $b^2-4ac=d^2$, we have that
$$P(x):=ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x-\frac{-b+d}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac{-b-d}{2a}\right)$$
Assume that $P(10)=\overline{abc}=p$ where $p$ is some prime of three digits. Then 
$$4ap=\left(20a+b-d\right)\left(20a +b+d\right)$$
which implies that $p$ divides $\left(20a+b-d\right)$ or $\left(20a+b+d\right)$.

Now $1\leq a\leq 9$, $0\leq b\leq 9$, and
$$0<\left(20a+b-d\right)<\left(20a+b+d\right)\leq 20\cdot 9+9+9\leq 198.$$
Hence $a=1$, and 
$$\left(20a+b-d\right)<\left(20a+b+d\right)\leq 20\cdot 1+9+9\leq 38.$$
Therefore $p>100$ can not divide any of them and we have a  contradiction!

Comment: Can we claim $a$ divides $20a+b-d $ or $20a+b+d$ instead?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Not necessarily if $a$ is not a prime.

Comment: @RobertZ In the final part, I did it differently: instead of bounding by $198$ and the lines that follow, I instead did this: claim that since as you said $p$ divides one of those two parenthesis, then the other must be $\leq 4a$, but since as you said $d \leq b$ they both seem $\geq 20a$, contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: @Santropedro Yes it is!

Answer (score 2):

We know $b^{2}-4ac=9$ with $a,b,c$ integers, then the equation $ax^{2}+bx+c (1)$ has rational roots.

Factorization of $ax^{2}+bx+c$ will be $a(x-t)(x-l)$ with $l,t \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now I can simplify to become every coefficient into integer number. It is the equation $(px+q)(rx+s)$.

$\bar{abc} = 100a+10b+c$, it is equal the equation (1) with $x=10$, then it is equal $(10p+q)(10r+s)$.

We conclude the number cannot be prime.

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these with the $p,q,r,s$ letters, see what happens. I suggest $299$ and $451$ as there will be just one way to get a product.

Here is one $252.$ $ \; \; 2x^2 + 5x + 2 = (2x+1)(x+2).$ $ \; \; \;252 = 21 \cdot 12$

```
130 = 2 * 5 * 13
154 = 2 * 7 * 11
230 = 2 * 5 * 23
252 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 7
275 = 5^2 * 11
299 = 13 * 23
330 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 11
396 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 11
430 = 2 * 5 * 43
451 = 11 * 41
530 = 2 * 5 * 53
572 = 2^2 * 11 * 13
630 = 2 * 3^2 * 5 * 7
693 = 3^2 * 7 * 11
730 = 2 * 5 * 73
830 = 2 * 5 * 83
930 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 31
992 = 2^5 * 31
```

Answer (score -1):

$c$ can take only $1, 3, 7, 9$ . [$abc$ is prime]

$b$ can take only $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$. [$b\neq 0$ as $-4ac$ can't be a square of a number]

$a$ can take $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

$b^2-k^2=4ac$.

Thus $b$ and $k$ both should be both odd or both even and $b>k$ as $c$ can't be $<0$.

$4ac=\text{Multiple of 4,12,28 or 36}$ as $c$ can take only $1, 3, 7, 9$.
$$(b,k)=(2,0),(4,0),(6,0),(8,0),(4,2),(6,2),(8,2),(6,4),(8,4),(8,6)(3,1),(5,1),(7,1),(9,1),(5,3),(7,3),(9,3),(7,5),(9,5),(9,7).$$
For all this values of $b$ and $k$, $a$ and $c$ can't assume such values such that $abc$ becomes a prime number. Thus, $b^2-4ac$ is never a perfect square when $abc$ is prime.